# AppRunner VPC connector with Internet Access

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-app-runner

I have one public API service running in Apprunner. Also I'm using a documentDB service to handle my NoSQL database. The database and Apprunner instance is running in the same VPC
I've followed the tutorial here and connected the service to the database successfully. -> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/observability-for-aws-app-runner-vpc-networking/

Now, I want to connect some public services on internet to get some data and make relations in the database. I can fetch some resources from online in some script I've added to the build step however inside from app I can't fetch. The request timeouts.

My VPC has default 6 public subnets and has been already connected with an internet gateway.

Build command I'm using
`npm install && npm run test:axios && npm run build`

Test Axios script: ( This works perfectly )

```js
// Import axios
const axios = require('axios');
// Make a request for a user with a given ID
async function main() {
  const result = await axios.get('https://catfact.ninja/fact');
  console.log(result.data);
}
main();
```

This is my simplified main application script: (TIMEOUT ERROR)
Error description:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.131.8.184:443
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1278:16) {
errno: -110,
code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '104.131.8.184',
port: 443 }
```

```js
const networkTester = async () => {
  const https = require('node:https');

  console.log('NETWORK TESTER');
  https
    .get('https://catfact.ninja/fact', (res) => {
      console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
      console.log('headers:', res.headers);

      res.on('data', (d) => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
      });
    })
    .on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(e);
    });
};

networkTester();
```